# Ошибка such unique or primary key already exists in the table при использовании jpa?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

Приложение на sprign+jpa и базой oracle11g
Настроен параметр генерации таблицы на основе предложенных сущностей JPA

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

Код сущности, при создании таблицы из который возникает проблема:

```
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "UserRecord")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "PR_KEY", unique = true)
    private String prKey;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    //surname Key
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    //type Key
    @Column(name = "type", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String type;

    //idPayment Key
    @Column(name = "idPayment", length = 64, nullable = false)
    private String idPayment;

    @Column(name = "User", length = 100000)
    @Lob
    private byte[] User;

    public UserRecord(String name, String surname, String type, byte[] User) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.type = type;
        this.User = User;
    }

    public UserRecord(String name, String surname, String type,
                            String idPayment, byte[] User) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.type = type;
        this.User = User;
        this.idPayment = idPayment;
    }
}
```

Здесь у меня `prKey` - это ключ в базе.
`name`, `surname`, `type` и `idPayment` - бизнес ключи, их комбинация должна быть уникальной внутри таблицы, но в плане бд это должны быть просто поля.

При попытке сгенерировать эту таблицу, получаю ошибку

```
 .SchemaExport perform ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table jpa
```

при этом запрос в логах пытался выполниться такой:

```
 Hibernate: create table UserRecord (PR_KEY varchar2(255) not null unique, name varchar2(100), idPayment varchar2(64) not null, riskMetric blob, type varchar2(100) not null, surname varchar2(100) not null, version number(10,0) not null, primary key (PR_KEY), unique (name, surname, type, idPayment))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я с хибернейтом как-то не очень знаком (совсем не знаком), но, насколько я могу судить, проблема где-то тут:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "PR_KEY", unique = true)  // вот тут надо убрать unique
private String prKey;
```

Проблема в том, что в сгенерированном запросе

```
create table UserRecord (
  PR_KEY varchar2(255) not null unique, 
  name varchar2(100), 
  idPayment varchar2(64) not null, 
  riskMetric blob, 
  type varchar2(100) not null, 
  surname varchar2(100) not null, 
  version number(10,0) not null, 
  primary key (PR_KEY), 
  unique (name, surname, type, idPayment))
```

вы просите сделать дважды одно и то же. Оракл создает уникальный индекс и когда вы пишете `PR_KEY varchar2(255) not null unique`, и когда вы пишете `primary key (PR_KEY)`. Вам нужно что-то одно, в данном случае убрать `unique` из описания поля - тогда запрос выполнится. Чтобы Hibernate сгенерировал его правильно, я подозреваю, достаточно убрать `unique` из аннотации.